# Iterate with for loop through binarized image possible?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, binary

this is my python code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("foo.jpg")

#here I can iterate trough each pixel since I have a 2D array
for x in range(img.shape[0]):
    for y in range(img.shape[1]):
    pass #maipulate each pixel

gary = cv2.cvtColor(img, COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bin = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#here I can not iterate trough each pixel since I have a 1D array
for x in range(img.shape[0]):
    for y in range(img.shape[1]):
        pass
```

My Question:
How can I iterate through each pixel of the binary image?
I want to use a sliding window search algorithm.

Comment: You may be looking for this: [Fast, optimized ‘for’ pixel loops with OpenCV and Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/08/28/fast-optimized-for-pixel-loops-with-opencv-and-python/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: The suggestion is how to make it faster, however I think you have trouble making it work? what's the error that it is giving you? Why can't you iterate in the binary image? the code as it is, does not look like it will fail, other than the typo in gary and gray

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because `threshold()` returns a tuple of 2 values: the threshold value you set (127) and a binary image. If you seperate these you can use the same double loop to access each value / pixel.
I've modified your code, as there where also a couple of typo's.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("foo.jpg")

#here I can iterate trough each pixel since I have a 2D array
for x in range(img.shape[0]):
    for y in range(img.shape[1]):
    pass #maipulate each pixel

gray= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh, bin_img = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

for x in range(bin_img.shape[0]):
    for y in range(bin_img.shape[1]):
        pass
```